Action of Hopf algebra of identity supported distributions on a Lie group
The Hopf algebra
of identity supported distributions on a lie group is cocommutative. It is well known that it is a group object in the category of cocommutative coalgebras. Is there a canonical cocommutative coalgebra
and a canonical action with group object the Hopf algebra of identity supported distributions on a Lie group?
